# BigQuery Data Transfer - Data Backfill vs Refresh

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Can I know the difference between data `backfilling` and `refreshing`, in the context of BigQuery Data Transfers.

Data Refresh window is a parameter that can be configured when setting up BigQuery Data Transfers for Google Ads and Search Ads 360 data (probably for some other BigQuery data transfers too).

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#refreshing
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-**Data transfer:**

> After you configure a data transfer, the BigQuery Data Transfer Service automatically loads data into BigQuery on a regular basis.

I.e fetch data from last 24 hours to you BQ dataset.

-**Backfills:**

> You can also initiate data backfills to recover from any outages or gaps.

I.e fetch data gaps, insert new lines that wasn't imported in the data transfer.

-**Refresh:** Overwrites a fresh copy of data in the destination table.

source:

[Cloud Storage transfers  |  BigQuery Data Transfer Service  |  Google Cloud](http://cloud/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#manually_triggering_a_transfer)

[What is BigQuery Data Transfer Service?  |  Google Cloud](http://cloud/bigquery-transfer/docs/introduction)

Comment: Thanks @ewertonvsilva.

For `Refresh` if the `Refresh Window` is 7 days, does it mean that on a daily basis the last 7 day data gets continuously (as a sliding window of 7 days)

I guess the idea is to capture any late recorded data?

Comment: Exactly, your understanding is right. The sliding window will visit the last 7 days and update them with the last data for those days.

Answer (score 1):

Further references on `RefreshWindow` :

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig